# Can we use list comprehension for nested for loop with outer and inner for loop having a statement each?

Tags: python

So far I have come across examples for List comprehension on which the outer for loop does not have any executable statemetn and the inner for loop has does something.. I was just wondering if we can use list comprehension with outer for loop and inner for loop have a statement each?

The examples that I have seen so far is :

```
[expression for x in x_values for y in y_values]
```

Was just wondering if the following can be acheived by list comprehension?

```
import re
def expandTrafficItemList(a):
    skip_list = []
    pat = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)-[A-Za-z]+(\d+)', flags=re.I)
    if a:
        c = a.split(',')
        for items in c:
            b = pat.search(items)
            [skip_list.append(b.group(1) + str("{:03d}".format(i))) for i in range(int(b.group(2)), int(b.group(3))+1)]
            
    return skip_list
               
        
a = "'TRF1-TRF25','RAW1-RAW4'"
expandTrafficItemList(a)
```

Here the outer for loop has only statement. was just wondering if that can be acheived via list comprehesion too. I tried to search through the documentation of list comprehension but could not get the desired results. Was just wondering.

Comment: You **can't**. Even if you could, it wouldn't be readable. It's better to just write a regular `for` loop because *readability counts*.

Comment: **Don't use list comprehensions for side-effects**

Comment: Also, you don't assign the result of list comprehension to anything but just using it's side effect (`list.append`). This is not pythonic. You should also consider turning it into a regular for loop.